many boys named "John". In this phrase it means “the boy is named by someone?
I read an answer and it had this phrase :

There are many boys named "John".

Does it mean “the boy is named by someone?” Is it grammatically right?
P/S: “A Boy Named Sue”, a song by Johnny Cash confused me too 

I don't understand the question. They are named John, just as you are named "yo yo" and I am named Daniel.

When "named" is used this way, it's not a verb that describes the process of naming someone. It's a past participle that indicates that the person has the specified name.
Many part participles can be used this way. For instance, we may say

the book titled The Martian
the house painted red


You're right that "named" can sometimes be used to emphasize the naming action, however the more common use treats the following as synonyms:

the boy is named John
the boy's name is John
the boy has the name John

and similarly, the following are synonyms:

the boy named John
the boy whose name is John
the boy with the name John

There's no special need to explain why one of these phrases was chosen rather than another.

Usually people use a name they were given at, or shortly after, birth by their parents, so, yes, the boys named John were given that name by someone. Sometimes people change their name, and then we say that they named themselves something.
"A Boy Named Sue" is a song written by Shel Silverstein and made famous by Johnny Cash. It is about  a young man whose father abandoned him at three years of age having named him Sue, commonly a feminine name, which results in the young man suffering from ridicule and harassment by everyone he meets. He swears that he will find and kill his father for giving him "that awful name".
